# How do I see which Twitter topics I've followed?

Tags: twitter

On twitter.com I've asked to follow some topics. Like "Entertainment" or "Sports".

And I randomly clicked some.

But how can I find the followed topics later? Is there a place to manage the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on More => Topics to Manage your topics

[image] [image]

Alternatively, a direct URL to the topics page is `https://twitter.com/<username>/topics`